# Shell project for executing background processes

Tags: c, shell, unix

```
int main(void) {
    char in[512];

    pid_t id;
    int status, y, x, i = 1;
    char *f[512];
    char *v;

    while(1)
    {
        printf("shell>");
        fgets(in,512, stdin);
        int size = strlen(in);// calculate dim of in execpt null
        in[size-1] = '\0'; //null at the end because ls\n not executable
        v = strtok(in, " ");
        f[0] = v;
        while (v = strtok(NULL, " ")) {
            f[i] = v;
            i++;
        }
        f[i] = NULL;

        y = strcmp(f[0],"exit");

        if (y == 0)
        break;

        id = fork();

        if (id==0) { //child
            execvp(f[0],f);
            perror("failure");
            exit(1);
        }
        else //parent
        {
            x=strcmp(f[i-1],"&");
            if (x != 0)
            waitpid(id, &status, 0);
        }
    }
}
```

In this code I can execute shell commands but I cannot execute the `command &` part. How can I make `execvp` execute a process in the background?

Comment: `if(f[0]=="exit")`. Strings in C cannot be compared using the `==` operator. Need to use `strcmp`.

Comment: Please learn to use the `{}` format tool at the top-left of the edit box to keep formatting for code/data/errorMsgs/etc. Good luck.

Comment: This post is unreadable.  Remember, if a line begins with 4 spaces, Stack Overflow treats it as code (and strips off those spaces).  To indent, just provide additional spaces.

Comment: now i can execute exit command ,but i want to implement in my code executing a command in the background like "ls&".. what should i do please?

Comment: @A.Mohsen: you should spend several days (or weeks) in *reading* (books and source code). We won't do your homework. A tiny shell is at least a thousand lines of source code, and we won't write them for you. You need to *learn* & *experiment*

Comment: i think here u can help me in the code but i did not ask u to complete my homework :D

Comment: I did help you by answering, and giving a lot of links which should be useful to you. The issue is not only in your code, it is mostly in your misunderstanding. So you should spend days or weeks in learning more, notably by reading. And your code should have many functions (in addition of `main`) and several data structures (so you'll need `struct` and pointers).

Answer (score 1):

**Read [Advanced Linux Programming](http://www.makelinux.net/alp/)**. Use [strace(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html) on *existing* programs (in particular, shells) to understand what [system calls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call) they are doing. Look at the list of [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html) and read more precisely the documentation of several of them (see [intro(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/intro.2.html)...). **Study the source code of some existing [free software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software) shell**, such as [sash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stand-alone_shell) & [bash](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/).

Don't forget that a system call (e.g. your call to [fork(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html)...) can fail. You should handle the failure, at least like:

```
 id = fork();
 if (id<0) { perror("fork"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); };
```

---

Regarding handling of ending `&`, you are looking after [job control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Job_control_%28Unix%29). Learn more about [process groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_group).

Your program does not implement [globbing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_%28programming%29) or [pipelines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipeline_%28Unix%29), and is not able to run some program with arguments (e.g. the command `ls a b` should run `/bin/ls`  with the three arguments `"ls"`, `"a"`, `"b"`), as every [shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_shell) should. See [glob(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/glob.7.html) & [pipe(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pipe.7.html).

Don't expect us to do your homework. You probably should code a much bigger program (probably a thousand lines, dozens of functions, several `struct` with pointers, ....), and think about its design first (this is where studying *existing* shell implementations would help you). In particular list first on a piece of paper (or some white board) a set of important functions and data structures to implement.

I would suggest to first code your shell to be able to run simple commands like `ls a b`, implement globbing (so accept `ls *.c`). Once that is done and debugged, consider implementing some builtins (notably `cd`), job control and pipelines. Before all that *study* the source code of some *existing* shell and of course the main system calls needed to implement it.

BTW, compile with all warnings & debug info (`gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`) and **use the debugger** (`gdb`) very often.